# function type parameter match in golang

Tags: go, goroutine

```
package main

type gens func(args...interface{}) int

func sum1(a int,b int,c int) int {
    return a+b+c
}

func sum2(a...interface{}) int {
    ret := 0
    for _,v := range a {
        ret = ret + v.(int)
    }
    return ret
}

func main() {
    var a gens
    //a = sum1
    a = sum2
    println(a(1,2,3))
}
```

consider above code, sum2 can work but sum1 doesn't.

compiler said "cannot use sum1 (type func(int, int, int) int) as type gens in assignment"

The reason why i ask because i want to write a goroutine scheduler that accpet variable-params functions, How can i do but rewrite lots of other func params to "args...interface{}"

thx!

Comment: You cannot. See https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface for explanation and solution.

Comment: thanks for reply ! @Volker

Comment: fist of all as you can see clearly you are passing slice of interface in your code. You should be passing interface and the get the underlying type which can be a slice. So In `sum1` you are actually passing int type parameters which can not be wrapped using slice of interface.

Answer (score 2):

```
type gens func(args...interface{}) int
```

You make type gens which is a function that has arguments in the interface format.

sum1 does not accept an interface as input so it gives you the error

Comment: in my opinion，define a function which argument are "x...interface{}" , you can pass any type, string, int and so on.  but in "function type" which exactly and definitely define a type you can not.  i find the answer on https://golang.org/doc/faq#How_do_I_get_dynamic_dispatch_of_methods

Comment: An interface does not need to have a type, but type gens is a func with arguments given as an interface and the func returns an int, the reason sum1 does not work is because the arguments are passed to to sum 1 as an interface but sum1 wants to get 3 int values

Answer (score 1):

```
package main

type gens func(args...interface{}) int

func sum1(a...int) int {
    ret := 0
    for _,v := range a {
        ret = ret + v
    }
    return ret
}

func sum2(a...interface{}) int {
    ret := 0
    for _,v := range a {
        if _,ok := v.(int);ok {
            ret = ret + v.(int)
        }
    }
    return ret
}

func main() {
    var a gens
    println(sum2(1,'2',3))
    //a = sum1
    a = sum2
    println(a(1,2,3))
}
```

i change code like this.  just better way to show how i think and study, excuse my pool english T_T

in sum2 func, arguments accept actually slice of interface,
you can pass any type string, int and so on, see above, i pass 1,'2',3， it's ok now.

but in "function type" which exactly and definitely define a type can not.
i can't run a = sum1 
compiler say " cannot use sum1 (type func(...int) int) as type gens in assignment"

in golang data struct, interface{} defined different from other, i think define a type will check more strict!
i find the answer on http://golang.org/doc/faq#How_do_I_get_dynamic_dispatch_of_methods

Answer (score 1):

Your functions `sum1` and `sum2` have different signatures and so sum1 cannot be assigned to type `gens`

Whenever possible you should avoid to use the `interface{}` datatype, as it requires runtime type conversions when you are working with it. (of course there are valid reasons to still do that, like unmarshaling etc )

You can read more about the empty interface here: http://jordanorelli.com/post/32665860244/how-to-use-interfaces-in-go

You could implement a type switch in sum2 to handle different primitive types and then add them:

```
func sum2(a...interface{}) int {
    ret := 0
    for _,v := range a {
        switch d := v.(type) {
            case int, int32, int16:
                ret += int(d)
            case float64,float32:
               ret += float(d)
        }
        if _,ok := v.(int);ok {
            ret = ret + v.(int)
        }
    }
    return ret
}
```

Or you could define an interface yourself which you then accept in the function like this

```
type Integer interface{
    Int() int
}

func sum(i... Integer) {
    result := 0
    for _, v := range i {
        result += v.Int()
    }
} 

type myfloat float64
func (m myfloat) Int() int {
    return int(m)
}
```

As for your use-case the last way would be recommended. Give each task a behavior like "run()" and then the scheduler knows what to do with it.